# NSIndexSet not set when user press enter after NSAlert

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsindexset

I have a very simple Mac app, that at one particular time, a button brings up a NSAlert with an input field. After that I take some actions on a NSTableView.
It works fine if the user presses the OK button, but if the user presses ENTER, it does not define the selectedrows

```
 NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setMessageText:@"Damage"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
NSInteger damage = 0;
NSTextField *input = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 24)];
[input setStringValue:@""];
[[alert window]setInitialFirstResponder:input];

[alert setAccessoryView:input];
NSInteger button = [alert runModal];
if (button == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
     damage = [input integerValue];
} else if (button == NSAlertSecondButtonReturn) {

}

//data
NSIndexSet *set = [self.tableView selectedRowIndexes];

NSUInteger index = [set lastIndex];
```

The index has the value of NSNotFound.

Could someone help fix it?
Tks

Comment: What actions? How can you deal with the `tableView` while modal view is visible?

Comment: When the modal is dismissed the code resumes on the IF of this code.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Does it have proper indexes before alert to present? Do you use `deselectRow`- or `deselectAll`-method?

Comment: I am not deselecting anything. I just want to populate the amount entered in the Alert into the table. If I press OK the indexset is populated, if I press Enter, id does not.

Comment: At least you can implement `tableViewSelectionDidChange` delegate method and store index in a separate property for your own.

Comment: thats a good workaround, but I would like to fix the current one, any idea?

Comment: Don't use an alert for input, use a sheet.

Comment: @Willeke maybe I did it wrong, but it just crashed the application. I followed Apple's instructions on using a sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I basically needed to add a key equivalent to the ENTER and it solved the issue:

```
 NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setMessageText:@"Damage/Heal"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
NSInteger damage = 0;
NSTextField *input = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 24)];
[input setStringValue:@""];
[[alert window]setInitialFirstResponder:input];

[alert setAccessoryView:input];
alert.buttons[0].keyEquivalent=@"\r";//new code
NSInteger button = [alert runModal];
if (button == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn) {
    damage = [input integerValue];
} else if (button == NSAlertSecondButtonReturn) {

}
```